# Android smooth transition on list items removed

Tags: android, listadapter, android-transitions

This gif illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: ideal behavior]

All of the ListView's items are removed except for the one that was clicked, and it smoothly transitions to the center of the ListView, now with a size of 1.

The problem is that whenever items at the *front* of the Adapter's ArrayList are removed, in other words when any other item besides the first is clicked, I get this discontinuous transition where the clicked item and its text jump to the position of the previously first item before transitioning:
[image: unwanted behavior]

```
final String[] items = {"foo", "bar", "The Quick Brown Fox", "qwerty"};
    final ArrayList<String> alItems = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));

    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.tv1, alItems);
    final ViewGroup main = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main);
    final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.theListView);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Remove all items except for the chosen one

            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(main);
            alItems.subList(0, position).clear();  // Remove items before clicked item
            alItems.subList(1, alItems.size()).clear();  // Remove items after clicked item
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

I suspect it has to do with the ArrayList getting set to a new ArrayList behind the scenes. What's a good way to accomplish the desired effect without jumps?

Answer (score 1):

Hack alert!!!

```
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(main);
    // set all but selected to empty string
    //   this leaves the list intact but only displaying selected item
    for (int i=0; i<alItems.size(); i++) {
        if(i != position) {
            alItems.set(i, "");
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // now wait a while & clear the list
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            alItems.subList(0, position).clear();  // Remove items before clicked item
            alItems.subList(1, alItems.size()).clear();  // Remove items after clicked item
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 200);     // 200ms or whatever delay looks good
```

If you're desperate enough, this might give you what you want.